IllegalArgumentException: Can not get field of POJO after running tests the second time. Tests fail after hot reload
I'm using the InfluxDB Java Client to manage metrics in a Quarkus service.
For that I have created an extension that provides a dev container of InfluxDB 2.
When I start my tests everything works, but when I trigger the hot reload by saving any file the test, that should send the metric to the database fails.
Here is the test. The model is at the bottom:
package mypackage.models.measurements;

import static mypackage.config.InfluxDBConstants.DefaultConstants.BUCKET;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance.Lifecycle;

import com.influxdb.annotations.Column;
import com.influxdb.annotations.Measurement;
import com.influxdb.client.InfluxDBClient;
import com.influxdb.client.InfluxDBClientFactory;
import com.influxdb.client.domain.WritePrecision;

import myextension.quarkus.devservices.influxdb.runtime.InfluxDBConfig;
import mypackage.config.InfluxDBConstants.JobMetricConstants.Fields;
import mypackage.config.InfluxDBConstants.JobMetricConstants.Tags;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;

/**
 * JobMetricTest
 */
@QuarkusTest
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class JobMetricTest {

    @Inject
    InfluxDBConfig config;

    public InfluxDBClient getClient() {
        InfluxDBClient client = InfluxDBClientFactory.create(
                config.url(),
                config.token().toCharArray(),
                config.organization().get(),
                config.bucket().get());
        assertTrue(client.ping());
        return client;
    }

    @Test
    public void testInitialization() throws InterruptedException {
        Instant testTime = Instant.now();
        JobMetric metric = new JobMetric("testJob");
        assertTrue(metric.duration == -1);
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
        metric.finish();
        assertTrue(metric.duration > 0);
        assertTrue(metric.job.equals("testJob"));
        assertTrue(metric.start.getEpochSecond() >= testTime.getEpochSecond());
    }

    @Test
    public void testInfluxReflection() throws InterruptedException {
        InfluxDBClient client = getClient();
        Metric metric = new Metric();

        metric.job = "job";
        metric.hasError = false;
        metric.duration = Double.valueOf(-1);
        metric.start = Instant.now();
        Instant stop = Instant.now();
        Duration d  = Duration.between(metric.start, stop);
        metric.duration = (double) d.getSeconds();
        metric.duration += ((double) d.toMillisPart()) / 1000;
        client.getWriteApiBlocking()
            .writeMeasurement(          // Line 72: Fails here!
                BUCKET,
                config.organization().get(),
                WritePrecision.NS,
                metric
            );


        
    }
}

@Measurement(name = "metric")
class Metric {
    @Column(timestamp = true)
    public Instant start;

    @Column(tag = true, name = Tags.JOB)
    public String job;

    @Column(name = Fields.HAS_ERROR, tag = false)
    public Boolean hasError;

    @Column(name = Fields.DURATION, tag = false)
    public Double duration;


}

Here is the exception:
2024-11-17 21:42:17,616 ERROR [io.qua.test] (Test runner thread) ==================== TEST REPORT #2 ==================== [Error Occurred After Shutdown]
2024-11-17 21:42:17,616 ERROR [io.qua.test] (Test runner thread) Test JobMetricTest#testInfluxReflextion() failed 
 [Error Occurred After Shutdown]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not get java.lang.Double field mypackage.models.measurements.Metric.duration on mypackage.models.measurements.Metric
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleFieldAccessorImpl.newGetIllegalArgumentException(MethodHandleFieldAccessorImpl.java:86)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(MethodHandleObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:444)
    at com.influxdb.client.internal.MeasurementMapper.getObject(MeasurementMapper.java:130)
    at com.influxdb.client.internal.MeasurementMapper.toPoint(MeasurementMapper.java:68)
    at com.influxdb.client.internal.AbstractWriteClient$BatchWriteDataMeasurement.toLineProtocol(AbstractWriteClient.java:386)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:212)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:212)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:5074)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:5082)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:546)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:265)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:702)
    at com.influxdb.client.internal.AbstractWriteBlockingClient.write(AbstractWriteBlockingClient.java:69)
    at com.influxdb.client.internal.WriteApiBlockingImpl.writeMeasurements(WriteApiBlockingImpl.java:253)
    at com.influxdb.client.internal.WriteApiBlockingImpl.writeMeasurement(WriteApiBlockingImpl.java:220)
    at com.influxdb.client.internal.WriteApiBlockingImpl.writeMeasurement(WriteApiBlockingImpl.java:207)
    at mypackage.models.measurements.JobMetricTest.testInfluxReflextion(JobMetricTest.java:72)

As I said a test rerun causes the exception, but stopping the tests and restarting them results in one positive test run until there is a rerun.
When I remove duration from Metric the same error occurs but with the job field.
I'm using Java 21, Quarkus 3.15 and InfluxDBClient 7.2.0

If your test runs fine with manual restart, may i suggest to refactor your reflection test logic in a try-finally and in the finally block try to close the client.

I created a wrapper class for the client and close the client now in a method which I annotated with @PreDestroy

Hot reload in Java have some limitations.
You need to use tools like JRebel or Hotswap Agent to improve the Java hot swap capabilities.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
